# Selenium IDE throwing an error when selecting an option from dropdown menu

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using selenium IDE, and I received an error when trying to select an option in a drop down menu

The error

> Element name = aggravation [] 556 [shares] not found.

This the command in question

`|select| |name=aggravation[]556[shares] |label=2|`

and this is the source code

```
<select name="aggravation[]556[shares]" id="aggravation_556_shares" class="shares" data-id="556" style=""><option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=aggravation_556_shares</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>**
```

or

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>id=aggravation_556_shares</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Followed by

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>value=2</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Or try extractingnthe XPath for `id=aggravation_556_shares`

Comment: i try what you wrote and still get same error message the element not found